# Copying plot with type=n in R to PDF doesn't copy plot points, only it's lines are shown in output pdf

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I've encountered a small complication with copying following example of random data to pdf. I realized that it is possible to copy it to png and probably to other bitmap formats as well but not to pdf.

I was trying to learn via this example how to plot "Males" and "Females" on a plot and show them all with different colors, etc. 
My device is windows.

---

```
    x<- rnorm(100)
    y<- x+rnorm(100)
    g<- gl(2,50)
    g<- gl(2,50, labels = c("Male","Female"))
    str(g)
    plot(x,y)

    # Plot function of (x,y) above will display it but it's not clear who is women and who is men, so I do following steps to plot it with different colors.
    # Plotting it with type="n".

    plot(x,y, type="n")
    points(x[g=="Female"], y[g=="Male"], col = "blue")
    points(x[g=="Male"], y[g=="Female"], col = "green", pch=19)
    fit<- lm(x~y)
    abline(fit)

    # Now I try to Copy it to png and that works fine.
    dev.copy(png,"myfile.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
    dev.off()

    # Now to pdf. This example doesn't work at all abd pdf won't even open in my pdf viewer.
    pdf("myfile.pdf",width=8,height=6)
    dev.off()

    # So I try this and I am able to open it but only "abline" and "x" and "y" are present not the points I specified for males and females.
    dev.copy2pdf(file="Examp1.pdf",out.type = "pdf")
    dev.off()
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening? PNG would be sufficient probably but it has it's flaws. So any idea how to copy it to pdf in R?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Note of interest from `?dev.copy` : "Note that these functions copy the device region and not a plot"

Comment: Again from the manual "The device copied to becomes the current device." Probably Did It mean that in the copy2pdf you tried to copy a png device? Because it is last copied... Note that If I run your code I obtain this Error message "can only print from a screen device"

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
pdf("myfile.pdf",width=8,height=6)
    plot(x,y, type="n")
    points(x[g=="Female"], y[g=="Male"], col = "blue")
    points(x[g=="Male"], y[g=="Female"], col = "green", pch=19)
    fit<- lm(x~y)
    abline(fit)
dev.off()
```

Explanation: This opens a `pdf` device, plots to it and closes the device.

Answer (score 1):

As I reported in my comment, This works fine, because I copy the original screen device and not the copied png device into pdf device. Note that device copy functions can copy only screen device and when you copy a device this becomes the current one.

```
windows()
x<- rnorm(100)
y<- x+rnorm(100)
g<- gl(2,50)
g<- gl(2,50, labels = c("Male","Female"))
str(g)
plot(x,y)

plot(x,y, type="n")
points(x[g=="Female"], y[g=="Male"], col = "blue")
points(x[g=="Male"], y[g=="Female"], col = "green", pch=19)
fit<- lm(x~y)
abline(fit)

dev.copy(png,"myfile.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
dev.off()
# How many devices are in list? 
print (dev.list())

# I must copy only screen device, that there is the previous one
dev <- dev.prev() 

# Now it works
dev.copy2pdf(file="Examp1.pdf",out.type = "pdf")
dev.off()
```